# How to execute bash from within a python file?

Tags: python, bash, execute

I am wondering if it is possible to execute bash code from within a python file. I don't mean run a completely different bash file. I am looking for a method to easily execute bash code that is one line or longer in length. Specifically, I want to execute this code I got help with from a question I asked earlier today.

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=(*/)
cd -- "${dirs[RANDOM%${#dirs[@]}]}"
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) if you do this a lot.

Comment: Also, why not just `os.chdir(random.choice(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir('.'))))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a string as a `sh` script (assuming POSIX):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call as x

x("""pwd
cd /
pwd""", shell=True)
```

You can specify the command explicitly:

```py
x(["bash", "-c", '''shopt -s nullglob
dirs=(*/)
pwd
cd -- "${dirs[RANDOM%${#dirs[@]}]}"
pwd'''])
```

Note: it only checks whether you can `cd` into a random subdirectory. The change is not visible outside the bash script.

You could do it without bash:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import random

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(random.choice([d for d in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isdir(d)]))
print(os.getcwd())
```

You could also use `glob`:

```py
from glob import glob

randomdir = random.choice(glob("*/"))
```

The difference compared to `os.listdir()` is that `glob()` filters directories that start with a dot `.`. You can filter it manually:

```py
randomdir = random.choice([d for d in os.listdir(os.curdir)
                           if (not d.startswith(".")) and os.path.isdir(d)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute bash code, but any effects of it (notably, `cd`) will only affect the subprocess it runs in, so there is no point. Rather, all of this is perfectly doable with Python commands (look into [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) or functions from the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module with the `shell` parameter set to true.

Note that many of the things you do in bash can be made just as easily within Python, while maintaining platform independence. For example I tried to run a Python script on Windows recently which was using many unix commands to do simple things like grepping some text and as such failed.

Comment: Warning: shell = True can be a huge security hole!

Comment: @ncmathsadist OP was asking how to execute something inside the shell though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [commands module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html)

eg:

```
>>> import commands
>>> (status,output)=commands.getstatusoutput("ls")
>>> print(output)#print the output
>>> print(status)#print the status of executed command
```

Comment: *“Platforms: Unix”* and *“Deprecated since version 2.6”*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

```
import os
os.system("system call 1")
os.system("system call 2")

(etc)
```

You can write shell scripts this way and use Python (nicer) looping and conditional execution facilities.